# TabStrip control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Is this still available?  I am unable to find it when I try to add it to my Toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a default asp.net Control as far as I know, maybe the control you're looking for is a third party control?

The Asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit has [Tabs](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx), that might do what you want.